# Null issue in Android Studio Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After I upgraded the Android Studio to Dolphin my project, which worked perfectly fine in Chipmunk, stopped working by giving me this weird error from `Gradle`:

[image]

There is no explanation of what is wrong except this weird error `null`.
I tried lots of stuff like:

1. Invalidating caches and restart
2. Deleting .gradle files
3. Upgrading the Gradle and Gradle Plugin. Right now versions are, for Gradle Plugin: `7.3.0` and for Gradle `7.4`
4. Updated google services to the latest version `4.3.14`

But none of this helped and I don't know what is wrong so any help is more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an Android Studio bug and is still active on the Google [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247244491?pli=1).

Apparently two people have found a workaround by:

- [Deleting](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247244491?pli=1#:%7E:text=I%20was%20facing%20the%20same%20issue%20and%20I%20got%20around%20it%20by%20deleting%20the%20%60.idea%60%20folder) the `.idea` folder and restarting Android Studio
- [Deleting](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/247211509#comment13:%7E:text=Delete%20.gradle%2C%20.idea%2C%20build%20folder%20in%20the%20project%20and%20restart%20Android%20Studio%20can%20fix%20this%20issue) the `.idea`, `.gradle`, `build` folders and restarting Android Studio

Hope this helps!